# How to replace single quote by two in php in a csv file with str_replace?

Tags: php, sql-server, csv, pdo

I have a PHP script that allows me to insert data from a CSV file into a SQL Server table.

I have on some lines this for example:

```
CL2096-CL;CREATURES OF LEASURE;h - Wetsuits;hd - Wetsuits Accessories;9'6" LONGBOARD DOUBLE;ETE 2020
CTEQJ5-RC;RIP CURL;c - Surfwear;ca - Surfwear Men;D'AMS S/S TEE;WINTER 2020/2021
BBBCJ1-RC;RIP CURL;b - Men Accessories;ba - Bags Men;DAY COVER 6'3;ETE 2020
BBBCK1-RC;RIP CURL;b - Men Accessories;ba - Bags Men;DAY COVER 6'7;ETE 2020
BBBCF1-RC;RIP CURL;b - Men Accessories;ba - Bags Men;DAY COVER 6'0;WINTER 2020/2021
```

I would like to replace the `'` with `''` in the file to be able to insert them. I tried `str_replace` but the replacement does not work, what can my error be due to?

```
<?php
    
    include("connexion.php");
    
    $dir   = '//macaroni/d$/ftp/Y2/GET/';
    $allFiles = scandir($dir);
    $dest = '//macaroni/d$/ftp/Y2/GET/COPIES/';
    
    foreach($allFiles as $file) {
    
        if (!in_array($file,array(".","..")))
        { 
            $file = $dir.$file;
            $filename = basename( $file );
            
          if ( strpos( $filename, 'BI3_' ) === 0 ) {
                
                  // truncate table  
                    $query = "truncate table dbo.Y2_Style";
                    $stmt = $conn->query( $query );
    
        
                   if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== false) {
    
                     $str = str_replace("'", "''", $file);
                     
                     // To remove BOM in the fist cell
                      fseek($handle, 3);
                
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 9000000, ";")) !== false) {        
                    if (empty(array_filter($data))) {
                        
                        continue;
                    }
    
                    
                   $query = "insert into dbo.Y2_Style (stylecode, brandname, department, category, description, season) 
               values('" . $data[0] ."', '" . $data[1] ."','" . $data[2] ."','" . $data[3] ."','" . $data[5] ."', '" . $data[5] ."')"; 
             
                       $stmt = $conn->query( $query );
                       
                       if (!$stmt) { 
                              $file3 = "D:/xampp/htdocs/retail_BI/errors/erreur_BI3.txt";                      
                              file_put_contents($file3, $query . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                     }
              }
                fclose($handle);
    
                //Moving the file to another folder             
                if(!rename($file, $dest . $filename)) { 
                       echo "error copy";
                  } 
              } 
           } 
        }
    }
      
    echo "good !";
    ?>
```

Comment: You're assigning `str_replace("'", "''", $file)` to the variable `$str`, which you're not actually using. You need to use `$str` somewhere, as it contains the replaced content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and let us know the result:

```
$files = glob('../App/*');
foreach($files as $file){
    $file_name = explode('/', $file);
    $file_name = end($file_name);
    if(strpos($file_name, 'BI3_') !== 0){
        $file_content = file_get_contents($file);
        $file_content = str_replace("'", "''", $file_content);
        $file_content = str_replace("''''", "''", $file_content);
        
        
        // Your Query
    }
}
```

Comment: @Patrick62, if possible, rewrite your code and use prepared statements and parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection issues.

Comment: @Zhorov i really agree by your idea but here is a solve problem comminuty not code sharing so the most important think is solving users problems. i think Patrick and another users that maybe use patrick and me codes, absolutly prevent the sql injections by true ways